# Mac10.13 HTTPS OpenSSL error

Tags: ios, macos, openssl, cocoapods

When I update to Mac 10.13.3,While I install HomeBrew and CocoaPods. the terminal will throw a OpenSSL error
the error is as follows:
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/': LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to github.com:443 
Failed during: git fetch origin master:refs/remotes/origin/master --tags --force

how to solve it.